# How much gas should cost for minting an NFT?

Tags: ether, gas, nft, erc-721

I am writing an ERC-721 smart contract on Ethereum, and the current gas for minting an NFT is around 5 USD. Some of my users think it is a little bit too high. Can anyone give me an idea that what a normal gas fee should be?

I think currently, the only way for me to reduce the gas fee is to remove some condition check, which is supposed to prevent some users perform strange behaviours like replay attacks.

Comment: surely it depends on how your contract is written.

Answer (score 1):

The price for minting NFT depends on many factors, such as current price of ETH, base transaction cost, base fee, and priority fee. How much gas should cost for minting an NFT depends on what price is acceptable to your users based on the factors above.

See: https://nftify.network/blog/nft-gas-fees

You can save gas fees when minting NFT by using Layer-2 sidechains, finding an NFT tool that uses lazy minting, using different blockchain networks, and customizing fees for transactions.

See: https://www.nftically.com/blog/five-ways-to-save-gas-fees-when-minting-nfts/